# How to increase laptop wifi strength?

Tags: laptop, wifi-configuration

My wifi router is at ground floor and my room is at 2nd floor. May mobile easily catch the wifi but my laptop drops the signal. What is efficient way to boost it. Should I do something with router or with my laptop?

Comment: How old is your laptop and how old your phone? Older models of laptops often do not have strong wifi modules, there is nothing you can do about. I don't know what router you use, sometimes you can disable a power saving mode, which makes the signal stronger, but the only other thing is changing the place of the router or using a repeater.

Comment: There is insufficient information to provide an answer  What model router  what model laptop and what wifi card does it have?  What bands are configured? (5gig is typically faster but has less range).  Can you reposition your router? Can you use ethernet over powerline?  Have you looked at alternative channels and what else is transmitting?

Comment: I put a Ubiquiti Access Point on my second floor and connected it via POE to the main network. That works for all devices on the second floor.